# iTunes Match error 4010 when adding songs to iCloud

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match

I have been using iTunes Match for 6 months or so and have been reasonably happy with the service. However over the past 2-3 days I get an error when I try to add new songs to iCloud:

```
We could not complete your iTunes Store request.
An unknown error occurred (4010).

There was an error in the iTunes Store. Please try again later.
```

I have restarted iTunes, rebooted my Mac but it made no difference.

Researching online shows lots of people going through all kinds of steps such as blowing away their whole iTunes library to fix this - often without success.  As this is not a new problem I am hoping someone will know the proper fix for it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you logout and log back in iTunes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what worked for me was to sign out of iTunes Store then sign back in.  This will disable iTunes Match. You then need to turn Match back on. It looks like it is starting completely from scratch (!) but it doesn't and instead adds all songs to iCloud that were missing.

I had 3 albums to add and I had to go through this process for each one.  I am assuming that something has changed or gone wrong on Apple's server side for it to start behaving this way when it previously worked fine.

Comment: Having had more issues with this recently, the key part seems to be to sign out of iTunes Store, sign back in then start iTunes Match again. This is a workaround though - I would like to know why it doesn't just work.

Answer (score 2):

I've gotten this error message when I've manually added mp3s to iTunes and it attempts to do the match.

Happened again just now and I tried a simple Store > Update iTunes Match and it seemed to jumpstart the process and complete it.

Remains to be seen if this will fix all future occurrences of this error message.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after importing songs from another iMac. After diligent troubleshooting, I found the cause of the 4010 error in my case. I had been using iTunes Family Sharing, and the songs that had been downloaded from other family members' accounts were the ones triggering the error. (I found this by selectively uploading only certain songs to iTunes, and discovered that all the songs that triggered the error contained other user names in the song purchase field.) After deleting from my library the songs purchased by other family members, I was able to use iTunes Match again, and did not get the 4010 error. Then I was able to re-download the family song purchases.

Answer (score 1):

It started a couple of weeks ago for me. I am using the newest MacBook Pro with all the latest updates. I find that I have to restart the entire machine then start iTunes again. So far, it works every time. Restarting the entire machine is really a hassle, but it does work. Once it works, it will get the same error if you try it again before restarting the machine.

PS: I have spoken directly with AppleCare and nobody seems to know what the 4010 error message means.

Answer (score 0):

In the menubar in the "store" menu try turning off iTunes Match, reboot, and turn it on again

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting iTunes match works for the songs you try to put onto iCloud, but once you start adding more songs and attempt to put those onto iCloud, you have to reboot again. This has also been happening to me over the past couple days, and I'm not sure why. It's getting really annoying having to reboot iTunes Match every song or so.